# Sum a column in a database but keep getting an error "Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for sum operator"

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am working in SQL server mgr.  I have tries several different approaches with no luck.  It appears that the column that I am trying to sum is not integer format.  With no DBA to adjust till next week I am stuck.  Closest I have gotten:

```
SELECT CAST([EpiCasesRounded]AS INT)

SELECT sum([EpiCasesRounded]) AS [EpiSummed]

FROM [IASDB_Partial_Delivery].[dbo].[DRG_EPI]
        where [DiseaseName]= [DiseaseName]
        and [PopulationName] = [PopulationName]
        and [PopulationYear] = [PopulationYear]
        and [GeographyValue]= 'China - Urban' 
        or [GeographyValue]= 'China - Rural'
GO
```

> error: (1017393 row(s) affected)
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Invalid column name 'EpiCasesRounded'.
>   Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for sum operator.

Answer (score 1):

SUM need a numeric column.

```
SELECT sum(CAST([EpiCasesRounded]AS INT)) AS [EpiSummed]
 FROM [IASDB_Partial_Delivery].[dbo].[DRG_EPI] 
where [DiseaseName]=   [DiseaseName] 
  and [PopulationName] = [PopulationName] 
  and [PopulationYear] = [PopulationYear] 
  and [GeographyValue]= 'China - Urban' 
  or [GeographyValue]= 'China - Rural' 
GO
```

Does it answer your needs ?

Be careful, in WHERE clause, AND and OR connectors need parentheses to set comparaison priorities.

Comment: Helped but now I am getting the following error: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Comment: What are your values are in EpiCasesRounded ?  int or decimal ? may be cast(... as decimal(20,4))...or check the numericity with  : SELECT EpiCasesRounded  FROM t1 WHERE try_cast('EpiCasesRounded  ' as int) is null

Comment: Successful run with                                                                         SELECT SUM (CAST([EpiCasesRounded] AS DECIMAL (38,0))) AS [EpiSummed]
FROM [IASDB_Partial_Delivery].[dbo].[DRG_EPI]
  WHERE [DiseaseName]= [DiseaseName]
  and [PopulationName] = [PopulationName]
  and [PopulationYear] = [PopulationYear]
  and (([GeographyValue]= 'China - Urban') 
  OR ([GeographyValue]= 'China - Rural'))
GO                 I do not see the EpiSummed column though.  Where would it show up in my results?

Comment: you should get column name 'EpiSummed' with the value of the sum below

Comment: (for the comparaison : ...and (([GeographyValue]= 'China - Urban') OR ([GeographyValue]= 'China - Rural')) : that works, but it could be more 'elegant' to write : ...and [GeographyValue] IN ( 'China - Urban',  'China - Rural')...

Comment: I expected a new column named 'EpiSummed' with values but there are no new column...weird.  Says Query executed successfully.

Comment: May be you can try : (1) COUNT(*) instead of SUM(...) to see whether lines are selected or not : if th ecount is greater than 0, you shoud get a result, but ... (2) SELECT CAST([EpiCasesRounded] AS DECIMAL (38,0)), CAST([EpiCasesRounded] AS DECIMAL (38,0))*2 FROM ... (without WHERE clause) to see data lines and check whether your column date is correctly converted or not